# How to get access to variable from another class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a searchBar in my **UserSearchController**:

```
class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Search"
    sb.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230, alpha: 1)
    sb.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    sb.delegate = self
    return sb
}()
```

And I want to **access and hide that search bar from the UserSearchCv:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.item]
    print(user.username)

    let userProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    (superview?.next as? UIViewController)?.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileController, animated: true)

    UserSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true //Something like this but it compiles an error
}
```

Comment: `UserSearchController().searchBar.isHidden = true` should compile because it's creating an instance of the controller. The way you're doing it is on the `UserSearchController` class itself, not an instance of the class. You'll need a reference to an instance of `UserSearchController`.

Comment: Are you declaring the instance of UserSearchController inside UserSearchCv? use that instance

Comment: @3stud1ant3 If I do 'userProfileController.searchBar.isHidden = true' it gives me an error

Comment: Oh wait, you might just need to do `self.searchBar.isHidden = true`. I'm guessing from your code that this `collectionView(_:didSelect)` delegate method is inside a `UserSearchController`?

Comment: @KaneCheshire nope, it's inside UserSearchCv

Comment: Are you declaring var of type UserSearchController inside UserSearchCv?

Comment: @ErikBatista You want to push VC to another VC and pass data using accessing other VC variable right?

Comment: @JitendraModi yes

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I just did that and searchBar.isHidden is now enabled but it a compile error happens saying "property 'self.userSearchController' not initialized at super.init call"

Comment: @3stud1ant3 it compiles the error on UserSearchCv

Comment: Check out my answer @ErikBatista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access that variable by object reference instead of class name. try this-

```
userProfileController.searchBar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Not sure that will compile unless `UserProfileController` has a search bar property. In the question, only `UserSearchController` has a search bar property.

Comment: @this doesn't compile an error anymore but the search bar doesn't dissapear. It's like I can't modify the search bar

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that
I am passsing array here. But you can pass any variable type as you want.
`ShareViewController` is your controller to push, and `arr_sticker` is your any varibale to pass. Remember both passing variable and assigning variable type would be same.

```
   let SV = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShareViewController") as! ShareViewController
   SV.arr_sticker = arrm_symbols
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SV, animated: true)
```

In another controller I have decalred array like

```
    var arr_sticker = NSArray()
```

In this controller when You `print` value of  `arr_sticker` you can get value you actually passed from VC to this VC.